# how to disable item in gridview in android

Tags: android, android-gridview

There is imageview in my gridview.I want to disable current item/image which is clicked in gridview of android.I am not able to do this.how to do this??
here is a code-

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int no,long lg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            id=no;

            final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
            alert.setView(input);

            alert.setPositiveButton("Check", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            String value = input.getText().toString();

              AlertDialog.Builder alert1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

              if(value.equalsIgnoreCase(country[id])){

                              // here i want to disable item
            alert1.setPositiveButton("Correct", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                      }
                    });

              }
              else
              {

              }
            }
            });

            alert.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: What have you done to disable an item?

Comment: and what you mean by `disable an item`?

Comment: 1st time when i click on any of item.then after performing operation next time that item should not be clicked/selectd

Answer (score 8):

You need a custom adapter.

Override the methods

```
ListAdapter.isEnabled(int position)
```

and override ListAdapter.areAllitemsEnabled() to return false.

Completely disables clicking, as well as selection graphics in the UI for GridView.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
   @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int no,long lg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // check for item clicked  say you have to disable image at position 4


      if (no==4){
// do nothing
}
else{
 final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            id=no;

            final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
            alert.setView(input);

            alert.setPositiveButton("Check", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            String value = input.getText().toString();

              AlertDialog.Builder alert1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

              if(value.equalsIgnoreCase(country[id])){

                              // here i want to disable item
            alert1.setPositiveButton("Correct", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                      }
                    });

              }
              else
              {

              }
            }
            });

            alert.show();
        }
}





    });
```

Comment: getting null pointer exception.i want to disable only select item. i.e. if i click on first item of my grid view.then only 1st image should get disable

Answer (score 0):

Override "isEnabled()" method inside the custom adapter as follows :

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    //other implemented methods

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return false;
    }
}
```