# How to disable the click of a specific image in GridView - Android

Tags: android, gridview, bitmap, android-arrayadapter

I have been going over the logic all night, and just cannot get an answer. I need for my drawables placeholder images, to not be clickable, and for my real images (photos from an SD card) to all be clickable for both regular clicks and long clicks. I have logged a million versions of how to write an if condition that would say something like: *if the image `Bitmap` is the drawable and equal to the `Bitmap` in the position clicked on, then process the click listeners*. But this can never happen! They are not ever equal. The `Bitmap` numbers always come up as different (which makes no sense to me), when I compare the drawable bitmap with the bitmap at the position clicked.

So I have tried another approach. I want to try what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697957/how-to-disable-item-in-gridview-in-android/13699167#13699167) to directly disable the drawable at its position. These methods, I put in my adapter class.

```
@Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return true;
    }
```

But the methods make no sense to me. Where/how do I call them in my situation? I don't understand how these are supposed to disable select items in my custom `GridView`. If you have any ideas, thanks.

**Here is my log statement values from logcat.** I got these by clicking on the drawable image in my `GridView`, but as you can see, the image `Bitmap` and the adapter position item are not the same. So how can I identify my drawable so I know to disable the click on there?

```
Value of adapter position item: android.graphics.Bitmap@430706e0
Value of drawableObject: android.graphics.Bitmap@4301fff0
Value of photoGridItem: android.graphics.Bitmap@4301a768
```

**PhotoTab.java**

```
package org.azurespot.cutecollection.phototab;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;

import org.azurespot.R;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 2/8/15.
 */
public class PhotoTab extends Fragment {

    private GridView gridView;
    File[] files;
    ArrayList<PhotoGridItem> photoList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<PhotoGridItem> adapter;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    private String[] numberSDCardFiles = null;
    PhotoGridItem drawableObject;
    PhotoGridItem photoGridItem;

    public PhotoTab() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_tab, container, false);

        adapter = new GridViewPhotoAdapter(getActivity(), photoList);
        // with fragments, make sure you include the rootView when finding id
        gridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.photo_grid);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        if(adapter.getCount() == 0) {
            // load contents of SD card
            loadSDCard();

            // add the default icons remaining, to GridView, if less than 24 files on SD card
            for (int i = 0; i < (24 - numberSDCardFiles.length); i++) {
                drawableObject = new PhotoGridItem(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.ic_photo_placeholder));

                adapter.add(drawableObject);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

        }

        setupGridViewListener();

        return v;
    }


    public void loadSDCard() {

        try {
            // gets directory CutePhotos from sd card
            File cutePhotosDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                    (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Cute Photos");
            // lists all files in CutePhotos, loads in Files[] array
            files = cutePhotosDir.listFiles();

            for (File singleFile : files) {

                String filePath = singleFile.getAbsolutePath();
                // this method makes size small for the view (to save memory)
                bitmap = decodeImageBitmap(filePath, 270, 270);
                photoGridItem = new PhotoGridItem(bitmap);
                // Check if this is a new bitmap file
                adapter.add(photoGridItem);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // get number of files in Cute Photos directory
        numberSDCardFiles =  new String[files.length];

    }


    private void setupGridViewListener(){
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView,
                                    View item, int pos, long id) {



                //Convert the bitmap to byte array, so can pass through intent
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                Bitmap bm = adapter.getItem(pos).getImage();
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                final byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), PhotoViewerActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("photo", byteArray);
                startActivity(i);

                Log.d("TAG", "Value of bm: " + bm);
                Log.d("TAG", "Value of adapter position item: " + adapter.getItem(pos));
                Log.d("TAG", "Value of drawableObject: " + drawableObject);


            }

        });

        // to delete a photo item
        gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> aView, View item,
                                           final int pos, long id) {

                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTitle("Delete")
                        .setMessage("Delete this cute photo?")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // delete from ArrayList first
                                photoList.remove(pos);

                                // get file name then delete it from SD card
                                String name = files[pos].getName();
                                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                                  (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Cute Photos" + "/" + name);
                                file.delete();

                                // after each item delete, replace with default icon
                                adapter.add(new PhotoGridItem(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                                R.drawable.ic_photo_placeholder)));
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                // do nothing
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        })
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .show();

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    // next 2 methods scale the bitmap image to a better size (so not huge)
    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            if (width > height) {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
            } else {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
            }
        }
        return inSampleSize;
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeImageBitmap(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        return bm;
    }


}
```

**GridViewPhotoAdapter.java**

```
package org.azurespot.cutecollection.phototab;

/**
* Created by mizu on 2/5/15.
*/
// package org.azurespot.cutecollection;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import org.azurespot.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 2/5/15.
 */
public class GridViewPhotoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PhotoGridItem> {

    ViewHolder holder = null;
    int position;

    public GridViewPhotoAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PhotoGridItem> photos) {
        super(context, 0, photos);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        this.position = position;

        if (v == null) {

            v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                            .inflate(R.layout.photo_grid_item, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.photo_grid_view);
            // stores holder with view
            v.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
        }

        // gets position of whichever photo you click on in the GridView
        final PhotoGridItem photoGridItem = getItem(position);

        if (photoGridItem != null) {
            Bitmap bm = photoGridItem.getImage();
            holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);

            // positioning the image in the GridView slot
            holder.imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            holder.imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(270, 270));
        }


        return v;

    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        ImageView imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Down vote with no comment is lame. I HAVE DONE my research. There is nothing out there on these methods. The docs are not explaining anything.

Comment: keep the position with the tag (the ViewHolder) ... onClick get position from tag and do what you need to perform.

Comment: @Noni, I don't understand why someone chose a down vote w/o any comment and chances are he/she won't come back to this post. Anyway, I have the power to up vote, balancing to 0, best I can do.

Comment: Hey thanks for that. It's been happening a few times in the last few days, I was starting to wonder if someone doesn't like me, haha. I always research first, then come to Stack. I think my post could be especially useful for others, because there are no other answers to this problem on here. I found only one and it was very vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unbelievable, but I found the right logic after all. I did not need the 2 List methods mentioned above, since those relied upon me identifying a drawable versus a photo in my `GridView` positioning. So at the time of adding my placeholder drawable to my grid, I also put them all into an `ArrayList<Bitmap>`, so that I could search the list and pull out drawable values when needed.

So then I added a conditional to the click listener's code, that said if my `ArrayList` of `Bitmaps` contains the bitmap found at the position of the view that was clicked, then do not proceed with executing the click listener's code. If it does not contain a `Bitmap` from the `ArrayList`, then go ahead and process it.

I checked if I could still add and delete items from the `GridView` and still have that conditional work, and I sure could. Below are the new additions in context.

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> bmList = new ArrayList<>();
```

...

```
    // add the default icons remaining, to GridView, if less than 24 files on SD card
    for (int i = 0; i < (24 - numberSDCardFiles.length); i++) {
        drawableObject = new PhotoGridItem(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.ic_photo_placeholder));

        // adds each drawable Bitmap to an ArrayList
        bmList.add(drawableObject.getImage());
        // adds to adapter
        adapter.add(drawableObject);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
```

...

```
private void setupGridViewListener(){
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView,
                                    View item, int pos, long id) {

                if(!bmList.contains(adapter.getItem(pos).getImage())) {
                    //Convert the bitmap to byte array, so can pass through intent
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    Bitmap bm = adapter.getItem(pos).getImage();
                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                    final byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), PhotoViewerActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("photo", byteArray);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }

        });
```

Comment: I think we discussed this before. The code to check for the bitmap image would not work, i.e. if(!bmList.contains(adapter.getItem(pos).getImage())). Because the Bitmap is different each time you call the decode method. Tell me if I am wrong since perhaps your code have changed.

Comment: If I am right from above comment, you can check on the path/file instead of Bitmap. Your adapter has to change a bit to contain the filename also.

Comment: I think what it was, is I was making a new object for each time I add a drawable (which I need to fix, I should never instantiate anything in a loop!) So my old way of comparing was taking the last drawable variable value put in the grid instead of the variable value of the grid drawable in a given position. By putting it in a list, I was able to have them all on hand, so it ended up working for that if conditional. But thanks, I didn't realize the decode method was doing that. ;)

Comment: Cancel what I said about decode method. I do not know about it. Is it all working for you on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Add your logic inside IsEnabled method like below

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    if(position == POSITION_U_WANT_TO_DISABLE) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

According to your code you always returning *true* (Enabled) inside that method.

Comment: Ach, you beat me to it. Excellent solution !

Comment: Thanks deniz, I will have to think about this. The positioning changes every time an image is deleted or added, so it makes this problem harder, because the position is not fixed. Plus the only position I can find is inside the click listeners themselves, which apparently get disabled at the start (right?) I think my understanding of how these methods is not clear. But I will keep thinking.

Comment: Do you see where I can get the position from? Having a hard time seeing where. The only way to check if it's the right position or not, is to get the Bitmap from the adapter at that position, which I've tried so many times, and the object in the position in the adapter is never the same as the drawable object (the item I want to be there if the position is to be disabled). I have tested this by logging. So I don't know how I would get the right position.

Comment: To further explain about the logging... I did a test where I click on the drawable image in my `GridView`, and found that the `Bitmap` logged at that position never matches the actual drawable `Bitmap` from when I first created the `Bitmap` drawable (that's the only way I know to identify a drawable versus an image). It always says it is a `Bitmap`, but the hashcode numbers are different, so for instance, the `adapter.getItem(pos)` will never return the same item as my drawable. Which is what I think I need to check if there is a drawable at that position or not.

Comment: @Noni photoGridItem.getImage() - what will it return for the cell which showing a place holder image?

Comment: No, I used the `drawableObject.getImage()` and that returns the drawable `Bitmap` that I added in the beginning of my class. The placeholder image. That `Bitmap` should be the one at `adapter.getItem(pos).getImage()`, but it oddly never is! I click the actual drawable in the `GridView`, and it returns a log of 2 different `Bitmap`s. Very strange. I must be missing something.

Comment: @deniz, I updated my question with the different log statement values I tried.